# Kernel build error test_real_width is negative

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, kernel

i ve no problem to cross compile the linux kernel v4.
i try to compile the kernel v5.15 and get an error.

Error:

```
make zImage -j8
  HOSTCXX scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so
In file included from /home/user/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/plugin/include/coretypes.h:367,
                 from /home/user/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/plugin/include/gcc-plugin.h:29,
                 from scripts/gcc-plugins/gcc-common.h:7,
                 from scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.c:3:
/home/user/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.5.0/plugin/include/real.h:74:68: error: size ‘-1’ of array ‘test_real_width’ is negative
   74 |   [sizeof (REAL_VALUE_TYPE) <= REAL_WIDTH * sizeof (HOST_WIDE_INT) ? 1 : -1];
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/gcc-plugins/Makefile:48: scripts/gcc-plugins/arm_ssp_per_task_plugin.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.user:552: scripts/gcc-plugins] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1246: scripts] Error 2
```

environment:
arch arm cross compiler 7.5 (dont want to change, because its the default for the programs)
Debian 11.5

i have no idea, where or what the error is. i ve googled that for over 2 hours but found no solution.

thank a lot for your help!

build with relative or absolute path

Comment: With an newer compiler building the kernel works. but i have to use the 7.5 version because i can get compatibility issues with mine build programs